# check item icon in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new at Extjs and Sencha. i started to design my UI and i could successfully add an iconCls with buttons. now i need to add icon to a checkitem menue http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.menu.CheckItem

but i couldn't ! even though i use iconCls property.
anyone have done this before ?

Comment: Did you check in developer tools if iconCls actually gets applied to the element of your menu item? Maybe there's a problem inside CSS...

Comment: They are already using the space reserved for the icon for the checkbox, do you want the image next to checkbox? That will require moving the separator line and lining it up

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich but i don't think there is a problem in CSS because it works fine with everything else

Comment: @Juan Mendes I am okay with that. how i could do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the icon right next to the text, you can just insert an image after the menu item is rendered

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
    floating: false, 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 
    items: [{
        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
        text: 'select all',
        listeners: {
            render: function(comp) {
                Ext.DomHelper.insertAfter(comp.getEl().down(".x-menu-item-icon"), {
                    tag: 'img', 
                    src: "http://flyosity.com/images/_blogentries/networkicon/stepfinal2.png",
                    width: 16,
                    height: 16
                });
            }            
        }
    }]
});
```

Ideally, you'd create a plugin or a subclass so you can reuse this functionality. The above code does not realign the separator, it's single separator for the entire menu, but it should give you a head start