# Add buttons in ExtJS menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs, frontend, extjs4.2

Is it possible to add `buttons` inside a `menuitem` using `ExtJS 4.2`?

I need to achieve the following:

[image]

*(To have an `edit` and `delete` buttons next to the `checkbox` of each `menuitem`. These will have their own handlers and will open new panels when clicking on them)*

---

I've tried to achieve it by creating a `container` per each `employee` and inside it add the `buttons` needed plus the `menuitem` but it's not working properly since I can't `click` the custom `menuitem` anymore after doing it and the design didn't look good at all.

---

However, I found a possible *"hint"* in the following *StackOverflow* answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213707/1178686

*(But this is not entirely what I expect since I don't need just an `icon`, I need a `button` with its own `handler` plus I don't know if interacting with the `DOM` is a good approach for this)*

---

Here's what I got so far and where I'm doing my tests:

***Live demo:***

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/hmqjqtqs/

***ExtJS code:***

```
Ext.define('Namespace.view.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    title: 'Panel',

    frame: true,
    floating: true,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: false,
    closable: true, 

    employees: null, 

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        Ext.apply(this, cfg || {});

        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'container', 
            border: false,
            items: this.createItems()
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }, 

    createItems: function() {
        var items = [];

        items.push({
            xtype: 'button', 
            text: 'Employees', 
            menu: {
                xtype: 'menu', 
                items: this.createMenuItems()
            }
        });

        return items;
    }, 

    createMenuItems: function() {
        var employees = this.employees || [], 
            items = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; ++i) {
            var employee = employees[i];
            if (employee) {
                items.push({
                    xtype: 'menucheckitem', 
                    text: Ext.String.format('{0} {1}', employee.name, employee.lastname), 
                    employeeId: employee.id, 
                    listeners: {
                        scope: this, 
                        checkchange: this.onMenuItemCheckChange
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        items.push({
            xtype: 'menuitem', 
            iconCls: 'add', 
            text: 'Add'
        });

        return items;
    }, 

    onMenuItemCheckChange: function(item, checked, eOpts) {
        console.log('Employee Id: %o was checked: %o', item.employeeId, checked);
    }, 

    destroy: function() {
        delete this.employees;

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Namespace.view.Panel', {
        employees: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Oscar', lastname: 'Jara'}, 
            {id: 2, name: 'Foo', lastname: 'Bar'}
        ]
    }).show();
});
```

***CSS:***

```
.add {
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/awicons/vista-artistic/16/add-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}

.edit {
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/outline/16/Pencil-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}

.delete {
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-edit-delete-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}
```

---

If someone knows a *"proper"* way to achieve this please let me know since I am not sure if one of the *configs* specified in the *API* for this component could help and I wasn't able to find a good example on the internet:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.menu.CheckItem

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're saying something like [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tup) is no good?

Comment: @incutonez the solution looks better but somehow I feel it's too forced, you are defining your own CSS even for doing a hover over, I think it's too much. I'd prefer trying another approach instead and not affect the styles that comes with the ExtJS/custom theme - I think this was a nice try btw (should be consider as the answer since it does what I expect but I'm a little bit picky).

Comment: Totally understandable, but if you're using Sencha CMD/scss files, you're not really affecting the theme, as it's valid to add your own styles/you'll be able to use their hover color variable.  I do like Semih's approach, as it uses a View, which I think really is your only other "proper" approach... unfortunately, that uses a lot more HTML, which could get hairy.

Comment: @incutonez Makes sense but I don't want to mess up with the CSS file that we currently have for the app although the approach is cleaner. Why don't you post this so I can accept it as the answer? it practically answers the question. I finally achieved this by doing the following, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8ebz9w2s/

Comment: It actually looks like you answered it yourself :)  Interesting approach... glad you could get it working that way, and you should post that as an answer.  But yes, I will post my comment as an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @incutonez To be honest, my solution fits what I need for the application I'm working on (you can read the comments from Semih's answer for better understanding) but the one who really answered this question is you (using a cleaner approach) so, can you please post your solution as an answer to accept it? thanks

Comment: True.  Still wouldn't hurt as an answer!  Yeah, sorry for the delay.  Posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably go the route of using a `container` and just trying to make that work.  I realize the styling might not be a nice as what the framework provides, but with enough fine-tuning, you could get it there... just make use of Sencha CMD, scss files, and their pre-defined CSS vars.

In this example, I do a quick unstyling of the buttons, so they can be clickable icons/areas, and I throw the employee record on the button itself... not really the best approach, but it works.  If you don't like listeners on each individual component like that, you could make the parent container have the listener, and in that function you would check the target's CSS class... but that's besides the point.  Working [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tup):

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyPanel', {
      extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
      title: 'My Panel',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      employees: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Oscar',
        lastname: 'Jara'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Foo',
        lastname: 'Bar'
      }],
      initComponent: function() {
        this.createMenuItems();
        this.callParent();
      },
      createMenuItems: function() {
        var items = [];
        var employees = this.employees;
        if (employees) {
          for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            var employee = employees[i];
            var containerItems = [];
            var checkboxCmp = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox', {
              width: 20
            });
            containerItems.push(checkboxCmp);
            containerItems.push({
              xtype: 'button',
              cls: 'my-custom-button',
              employee: employee,
              width: 22,
              text: '',
              iconCls: 'edit',
              listeners: {
                click: this.onClickEditButton
              }
            });
            containerItems.push({
              xtype: 'button',
              cls: 'my-custom-button',
              employee: employee,
              width: 22,
              text: '',
              iconCls: 'delete',
              listeners: {
                click: this.onClickDeleteButton
              }
            });
            containerItems.push({
              xtype: 'component',
              html: '<div style="border-left:1px solid #000;height:100%; display: inline-block;"></div>'
            });
            containerItems.push({
              xtype: 'button',
              cls: 'my-custom-button',
              textAlign: 'left',
              checkboxCmp: checkboxCmp,
              employee: employee,
              flex: 1,
              text: employee.name + ' ' + employee.lastname,
              listeners: {
                click: this.onClickEmployee
              }
            });
            items.push({
              xtype: 'container',
              layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
              },
              overCls: 'over-item-cls',
              items: containerItems
            });
          }
        }
        this.tools = [{
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'Employees',
          menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            items: items,
            plain: true
          }
        }];
      },
      onClickDeleteButton: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        alert('clicked delete, check console for employee');
        console.log('delete', button.employee);
      },
      onClickEditButton: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        alert('clicked edit, check console for employee');
        console.log('edit', button.employee);
      },
      onClickEmployee: function(button, event, eOpts) {
        alert('employee checkbox changed, check console for employee');
        console.log('employee', button.employee);
        var checkboxCmp = button.checkboxCmp;
        if (checkboxCmp) {
          checkboxCmp.setValue(!checkboxCmp.getValue());
        }

      }
    });
    Ext.create('MyPanel');
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.add {
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/awicons/vista-artistic/16/add-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}

.edit {
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designcontest/outline/16/Pencil-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}

.edit:hover,
.delete:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.delete {
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/16/Actions-edit-delete-icon.png') !important; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: block;
}

.over-item-cls {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

a.my-custom-button.x-btn-default-small {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

a.my-custom-button.x-btn-default-small span {
    color: #ababab;
}

a.my-custom-button.x-btn-default-small:hover span {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are insterested in using tpl in menu items: If you are, I can improve this code below. And Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tt3

```
        Ext.define('Image', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name:'buttonText1', type:'string' },
            { name:'buttonText2', type:'string' },
            { name:'menuText',    type:'string' }
        ]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id:'imagesStore',
        model: 'Image',
        data: [
            { buttonText1:'edit', buttonText2: 'add', menuText:'Drawing', id: '1' },
            { buttonText1:'edit', buttonText2: 'add', menuText:'Advanced', id: '2' },
        ]
    });

    var imageTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for="."><table>',
            '<div class="menu-row">',
            '<input type="checkbox" id="check{id}">',
            '<button class="{buttonText1}">{buttonText1}</button>',
            '<button class="{buttonText2}" >{buttonText2}</button> {menuText}',
            '</div>',
            '<table></tpl>'
    );

    var dataview = Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
            itemId: 'idDataView',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('imagesStore'),
            tpl: imageTpl,
            itemSelector: 'div.menu-row',
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(dataview, record,items) {
                    Ext.each(items.children, function(item) {
                        if (item.id == 'check'+ record.get('id')) {
                            item.checked == false ? item.checked = true : item.checked = false;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
    });

    var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
                text: 'menuButton',
                margin: '100 100 100 100',
                menu: {
                    //plain: true,
                    items: [dataview],

                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function(menu) {
                            var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
                                Ext.each(menu.down('#idDataView').getEl().dom.children, function(nodes) {
                                    Ext.each(nodes.children, function(node) {
                                        if (node.className == 'edit') {
                                            node.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                               alert('edited'); 
                                            });
                                        } else if (node.className == 'add') {
                                            node.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                               alert('added'); 
                                            });
                                        }
                                    })

                                });
                             });
                            task.delay(100);  
                        }
                    },
                },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
```

Comment: +1 for the nice try, but somehow when I click on the checkboxes is not working fine. Also, if you switch the ExtJS version to 4.2 you will see that some styles are lost like the hover over - thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't like my solution while I was doing. Because, adding event to each dom element is not a proper way. That's why, I didn't complete my code and I said I can improve if you want me keep going. Anyway, I see you and incutonez have made great working solutions. Especially, I liked the incutones answer, which seems more clear, but your way is really creative. I'll be also glad to vote both answer if you both add your solutions as answers.

Comment: Yes, I like incutonez solution too, it's more clear but the problem is that you need to create new styles for the custom menu that you are creating and I just wanted to continue using the styles that comes from ExtJS when using menu items. In the other hand, I think I will use my approach because the app I am working on has more things, like a big dot that appears when selecting each menu item so, If I add the edit/delete buttons at the same level that the solutions here do, then I believe it will mess up and hopefully mine adds them on the right side (I don't know if you get what I'm saying).

Comment: I'll add my answer later but I think the one who really answered this question is incutonez, I just hope he provides  an answer later instead of just a comment.